# React native library doesn't found in Gradle project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, react-native

I have react native project which uses react-native@0.36.0.
I am trying to upgrade the version to 0.40.0.
In build.gradle there are these rows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$projectDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22'
}
```

When have updated the npm version of react-native all the "import com.facebook.react" became red.
What am I missing?

Thanks.

UPDATE: I see that in /build/intermediates/exploded-aar there is version 0.36.0 despite the fact that in app.iml I have the rows:

```
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.40.0/jars" />
```

and

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="react-native-0.40.0" level="project" />
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I am facing a similar issue.